# CNContactViewControllerDelegate not called when using the Coordinator pattern in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, cncontactviewcontroller

I've been grinding on this issue for quite a few days now and it seems like SwiftUI's relative "newness" doesn't seem to help me with this.

My gut feeling is that I'm somehow using `CNContactViewControllerDelegate` wrong but both Apple's documentation as well as other questions on SO make it seem like it should work. Maybe, it is also caused by `.sheet`'s handling, but I wasn't able to isolate the issue as well. Not wrapping `NewContactView` inside `NavigationView` also made no difference and removed the default navigation bar (as expected).

I'm showing the `CNContactViewController` with `init(forNewContact:)` to give the app's users an ability to add new contacts. Persisting and everything works fine, however, none of the delegate's functions seem to get called.

Neither dismissing the modal with the "swipe to dismiss" gesture introduced in iOS 13 calls the delegate function, nor using the navigation buttons provided by `CNContactViewController`.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import ContactsUI

struct NewContactView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, CNContactViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

        func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) {
            if let c = contact {
                self.parent.contact = c
            }
            viewController.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        
        func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, shouldPerformDefaultActionFor property: CNContactProperty) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

        var parent: NewContactView

        init(_ parent: NewContactView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }

    @Binding var contact: CNContact

    init(contact: Binding<CNContact>) {
        self._contact = contact
    }

    typealias UIViewControllerType = CNContactViewController

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NewContactView>) -> NewContactView.UIViewControllerType {
        let vc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: CNContact())
        vc.delegate = makeCoordinator()
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: NewContactView.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NewContactView>) {
    }
}
```

The view's code for showing the controller looks like this:

```
.sheet(isPresented: self.$viewModel.showNewContact, onDismiss: { self.viewModel.fetchContacts() }) {
        NavigationView() {
                NewContactView(contact: self.$viewModel.newContact)
        }
}
```

Thank you for any pointers! Rubberducking sadly didn't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI creates coordinator by itself and provides it to representable in context, so just use

```
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NewContactView>) -> NewContactView.UIViewControllerType {
        let vc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: CNContact())
        vc.delegate = context.coordinator      // << here !!
        return vc
    }
```